Migrating to Spring Boot v2 to v3 and Getting ClassNotFoundException for javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
While migrating from Spring Boot v2.7.14 to v3.3.2, I'm getting the below error :
ClassNotFoundException for javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
To resovle the issue I have to add the below dependency :
<!-- Additional dependencies after moving from Spring Boot v2 to v3 -->

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>

Request
Could you please resolve the issue with the Spring Boot 3 versions of manually adding this dependency in the pom.xml?

What's the stack trace of the ClassNotFoundException?

Spring Boot 3 upgraded to Jakarta EE 9+, which means you have to use jakarta.xml-bind 3.0 or higher instead of javax.xml.bind 2.3, which uses the jakarta.xml.bind namespace instead of javax.xml.bind.

But I'm not explicitly using import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;  in my code. It's something being using behind the scenes by the dependencies. I"m still not sure which dependency is causing the issue.

I faced same issue when i was updating my project sporing boot version.jakarta  and  javax both library have same annotation but you have to use javax.
You may be import from import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement; 
You have to Import from  import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement; 
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency> 

by changing import i solve my problem.

But I'm not explicitly using import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;  in my code. It's something being using behind the scenes by the dependencies. I"m still not sure which dependency is causing the issue.
